# Logic behind Verilog code

Tags: verilog

```
input x;
input y;
input[10:0] z;

wire a;

assign a = x & y & (|z);
```

I'm looking at a code and don't understand what the line on assign does. An explanation as to what this line means would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wire a` is driven by some combinational logic. In that combinational logic all the bits of `input [10:0] z` are ORed together (that's what `|z` means). Then the result of that ORing (ie the output of an 11-input OR gate) is ANDed together with inputs `x` and `y`. The result of that ANDing (ie the output of that 3-input AND gate) is assigned to `wire a` (ie that 3-input AND gate drives `wire a`).

Answer (score 1):

`z` is a eleven bit wide signal.
`|` is the `or reduction` of a signal.
`(|z)` will be true(`1`) if there is at least one bit in `z` that is `1`. On the other hand, `(|z)` will be false(`0`) if all bits in `z` are `0`. This means that the `or reduction` of a signal is the short way to test if a signal is `0`.

```
|z <==> z==0;
```

`&` is the `bitwise and`. It means that for a multibit signal, it will perform the `and` operation between each bit index. The result will the be the same size as the inputs.   e.g:

```
wire [2:0] signal1, signal2, result;
assign result = signal1 & signal2;
```

is equivalent to(bit to bit):

```
assign result[0] = signal1[0] && signal2[0];
assign result[1] = signal1[1] && signal2[1];
assign result[2] = signal1[2] && signal2[2];
```

or(with concatenation):

```
assign result = {signal1[0] && signal2[0],signal1[1] && signal2[1],signal1[2] && signal2[2]}
```

In your expression though, as all the signals are 1 bit wide (`a`,`b` and `(|z)`) so `&` or `&&` can be used equivalently.

A schematic doing what you expression states with simple 2-inputs gates is the following:

[image: Simple gates schematic of the assignment]

More informations on operators and how translating them in hardware can be found on [this site](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators.html).